# docview: suppress "File X is too large, really open?" confirmation

Tags: find-file, docview, large-files

Is it possible to avoid the "File X is too large, really open?" confirmation?

If not, would it be possible for Emacs to remember my answer the first time I visited a large file? If I visited it once, I will surely want to really visit it again.

Comment: I'm not convinced your final sentence is a safe generalization.  That sort of warning is generally added in response to enormous files causing performance/stability problems.  If the file in question is large enough to cause problems on your computer (vs the low end system likely considered by the devs in setting default the threshold) throwing a "you're playing with fire" reminder is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable is `large-file-warning-threshold`. Documentation:

```
large-file-warning-threshold is a variable defined in `files.el'.
Its value is 10000000

Documentation:
Maximum size of file above which a confirmation is requested.
When nil, never request confirmation.

You can customize this variable.

This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
version 22.1 of Emacs.
```

I found this by using `helm-apropos` and searching for "large file".

Comment: See also [this thread](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108259/how-do-i-stop-emacs-from-asking-me-if-i-want-to-load-a-large-file) for more information.

Comment: @Dan, That is quite a detailed answer for such a seemingly simple question. Thanks.